# Parameters on evm opcode create

Tags: evm, assembly, opcode

Why the usual way to create a contract with evm opcodes use `add` and `mload`, for example:

```
bytes memory bytecode = hex"600580600c6000396000b800602a600052b8";
...
assembly {
    _address := create(0, add(bytecode, 0x20), mload(bytecode))
}
```

I can't understand why adds `0x20` to the initial position and why `mload(bytecodes)` returns the size of bytecodes. Is someone can point me doc related I'll appreciate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because memory variables are treated as pointers from in solidity assembly - and that pointer points to the start in memory of the variable. The way arrays are stored in memory in Solidity is with the first 0x20 (32) bytes being the length of the data in the array, and then the actual data directly following, which is why `add(bytecode, 0x20)` is needed to get the start of the actual data in `bytecode` . Since the first 0x20 bytes are the length of the array, `mload(bytecode)` grabs the length of the bytecode to store.

Edit: To fully understand this, you should read through the [Assembly](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/assembly.html) as well as [Miscellaneous](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/miscellaneous.html) (mainly the details about storage/memory layout) sections of the Solidity Docs